# How to show a single item list of values that repeat due to a change in service

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, reporting-services, group-by

I need to find a way to list only accounts that have a change in service. In the databse I was able to get them to list twice showing the change by the query listing them as:

```
*--------------------*
|SERVICE      ACCOUNT|
*--------------------*
|FULL PACKAGE   003  |
|FULL PACKAGE   004  |
|GRASS ONLY     005  | 
|FULL PACKAGE   005  |
|GRASS ONLY     006  |
|FULL PACKAGE   007  |
|GRASS ONLY     010  |
|FULL PACKAGE   010  |
*--------------------*
```

The queries I have tried using for this so far are

**My Primary attempts**

[image]

I am able to return with the second query a list like what is above, the other two return nothing (I'm assuming for the first one it's because looking for a value with literally both in the cell?)

But the thing is, I only need the account numbers that repeat based on: WHERE contract.SERVICE='GRASS ONLY' AND contract.SERVICE='FULL PACKAGE' in the other column

Ideally the return result would be like:
1 ... 005
2 ... 010

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select account
from mytable
where service in ('GRASS ONLY', 'FULL PACKAGE')  -- either one
group by account
having count(service) = 2                        -- both match
```

This gives you `account`s that have both `service`s. If there are duplicate `(account, service)`, then you need  `having count(distinct service) = 2` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm (as I'm sure you've gathered) brand new to this lol. You're the best!